# How to get keys from the inner dictionaries of a nested dictionary using comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

I am trying to find the keys of the dictionaries inside a dictionary and write them into a set using set/list comprehension.

So it looks like this:

```
dict_o_dicts = {
    1: {'de': 'eins', 'en': 'one' },
    2: {'de': 'zwei', 'en': 'two' },
    3: {'ru': 'три', 'gr': 'τρία' },
    0: {'ru': 'ноль' }}
```

I can get it working using:

```
result = set()
for x in dict_o_dicts:
    for y in dict_o_dicts[x]:
        result.add(y)
```

Gives the required output:

```
{'de', 'en', 'gr', 'ru'}
```

But I am required to solve it using a set/list comprehension. I tried everything, but I always get stuck somewhere. For example:

```
result = [set(dict_o_dicts[x].keys()) for x in dict_o_dicts]
```

It gives me a list of sets, but how could I unite them? I just don't know how to solve it in one line.

Comment: There's [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap). `set(ChainMap(*dict_o_dicts.values()))`

Comment: Does the entire expression have to be a comprehension or is the only requirement that it has to be a one-liner?

Comment: Is there a way to only use the standard library?

Comment: it only has to be a one-liner

Comment: @goinginsane23, [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) is a part of standard library.

Comment: @MichaelButscher This gives me an Error: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'

Comment: @goinginsane23, I guess you missed `*`.

Comment: You can have more than one "for" in a comprehension. You can use the same loop-nesting as in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short attempt (is this code golf? :p)

```
set().union(*dict_o_dicts.values())
```

output: `{'de', 'en', 'gr', 'ru'}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use double (or more) for loops in set (or other) comprehensions:

```
>>> { k for sub_dict in dict_o_dicts.values() for k in sub_dict }
{'de', 'gr', 'ru', 'en'}
```

Comment: you can replace set() syntax with {} so you have a nested set comprehension. what currently it is using looks like a gen expression and a set() constructor, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = set()
[[result.add(y) for y in dict_o_dicts[x]] for x in dict_o_dicts]
```

You can do something like this.

The output:

```
{'ru', 'gr', 'en', 'de'}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it with a single level comprehension, you could use unpacking with the set's union method:

```
set().union(*(v for v in dict_o_dicts.values()))

{'gr', 'ru', 'de', 'en'}
```

*note that the comprehension is not actually required in this case*

```
set().union(*dict_o_dicts.values())

{'gr', 'ru', 'de', 'en'}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all possible keys from a nested dict of any depth try this recursive function:

```
def get_all_keys(d):
    res=[]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if type(v) == dict: 
            # comment this line if you need only last level
            res.append(k)
            res = res + get_all_keys(v)
        else: res.append(k)
    return res
```